# Selecting a DataTables Row when clicked

Tags: jquery, datatables

I've been playing around with datatables.net and my table now loads data from an array of json objects.  Now what I'd like to do is grab the ID of one of these objects (just a property) when someone clicks a line so I can open a dialog.

I've found a kludgy mechanism by using the fnRowCallback to load the ID as an attribute on the TR element but this breaks when the rows are sorted.

```
var tableData = [
            { id: 196402, name: "Joe Bloggs", age: 25, gender: "Male"},
            { id: 257820, name: "Jane Bloggs", age: 22, gender: "Female"},
            { id: 33025, name: "Sam Smith", age: 27, gender: "Female"}
        ];


oTable = $('#MyTable').dataTable({ "aaData": tableData,
            "aoColumns":
                [
                    {"mData": "name"},
                    {"mData": "age"},
                    {"mData": "gender"}
                ],
            "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {
                $(nRow).attr('id', aData.id); // this breaks if the grid is sorted!
            }
            });

            $("#MyTable tbody tr").click( function( e ) {               
                alert($(this).attr('id'));
            });
```

Is there a better method of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From: http://www.datatables.net/api

```
$('#example tbody td').click( function () {
    // Get the position of the current data from the node
    var aPos = oTable.fnGetPosition( this );

    // Get the data array for this row
    var aData = oTable.fnGetData( aPos[0] );

    // Update the data array and return the value
    aData[ aPos[1] ] = 'clicked';
    this.innerHTML = 'clicked';
  } );
```

I love datatables but it's really worth spending a while learning them... I've still got a long way to go TBH ;-)

Hope that helps.

D